# How are commands on run dialog executed?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have read somewhere, that the commands entered in the *run* dialog box are executed as if they are executed using the `start` command in CMD. Which I believed was the case (as i could executed applications registered at **app paths** key just by their name using run).

But i noticed a little bit of deviation from this behavior when I tried to run a command on *run* without extensions. To illustrate this behavior:-

I added `.msc` and `.MSC` (i am unaware of extension case sensitivity/insensitivity on windows) to the **PATHEXT** environment variable, such that it became like this:-

`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.msc`

After this I executed the following command in CMD, to start the ***Device Manager***:-

`start devmgmt`

Which lead to execution of Device Manager.

But when i typed in the following command in *run* dialog box:-

`devmgmt`

it prompted me with an error stating:-

[image]

Well, If my statement in the first paragraph is correct, then why did I ended up with an error in the second case?

**P.S.:-** Upon googling about this issue before, i read *several* article which stated *run* prompt inherits **PATHEXT** values of CMD, for extension resolution. And if it doesn't, then there exists an policy (in *gpedit* or something) which makes the run prompt only possess the default **PATHEXT** values!! (correct me if i was wrong here)

Comment: Why don't you just tell us what the task is you're trying to perform, but isn't working as expected? You've told us that you've added an `.MSC` extension to `%PATHEXT%` and that when you type `devmgmt` in the 'run' dialog it doesn't open Device Manager. Are those two things related? is `devmgmt.msc` the command you're trying to run?

Comment: @Compo Sorry, If i was a bit unclear in my words.  What I meant was that *device manager* could be executed via entering the command `devmgmt.msc` in the command line. I wanted to get rid of entering the extension ever time I have to run it, and therefore added the `.MSC` to the `%pathext%` environment variable, so that the next time i try to run it, I don't have to provide the extension for it.

Comment: Due to which i was able to execute `start devmgmt` (see no extension provided) in the commandline successfully. But when i tried to do the same in the *run* dialog box, it gave be the aforementioned error!! So, why am i able to run the command in CMD (I know coz of `%pathext%` entry) without extension and  is required to provide the extension when trying to run it using the *run* prompt. Even though *run* is said to execute command similar to  running it via `start` command.

Comment: `devmgmt.msc` is technically an argument to `mmc.exe`. To correctly run the Device Manager, the command is `mmc devmgmt.msc` or more properly `C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe devmgmt.msc`. Why don't you just create a shortcut, with that as your target?

Comment: PathExt is specific to CMD.exe. In CreateProcess that is what you call to actually start a program it will ONLY add .exe to find the file. It will execute any filename given to it. EG If CMD can't find a file association for a file it gives up and passes it to CreateProcess. Typically extensionless files don't have an association so CMD will execute but Explorer won't.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa

Comment: In CMD's `start` command, the primary `PATH` w/ `PATHEXT` file search is not equivalent to the shell API file search in the shell-execute family. But if `start` fails to find a file, it still lets the shell API try, which allows using shell protocols and "App Paths" commands.

Comment: I stepped through what the shell API does in a debugger. Unlike CMD, the shell API search uses a hard-coded list of file extensions -- ".pif;.com;.exe;.bat;.lnk;.cmd". It calls `FindFirstFileW` on every directory in the search path, filtered in this case on "devmgmt.*", and looks for either an exact match on "devmgmt" or a match with one of the allowed extensions, which are matched case insensitively.

Comment: BTW, adding ".MSC;.msc" to `PATHEXT` doesn't serve much point. As it happens, CMD is buggy since it relies on the filesystem being case insensitive for its use of the `PATHEXT` extensions. In Windows 10, it's possible to set an NTFS directory as case sensitive, which breaks CMD's naive assumption. But what about ".MSc" or ".msC" or any other letter case combination? The bug in CMD just needs to be fixed. If a directory has both a "devmgmt.msc" and "devmgmt.mSC" file, it should run the first one that's matched case insensitively, whichever that is. It's badly defined, but that's user error.

Comment: @ErykSun Could you explain what does **shell API** mean in this context? I am not much aware of Windows Internals and it's terminologies

Comment: The Windows concept of a graphical UI terminal and shell is an extension of the classic text UI terminal and shell. A terminal session consists of a window station (WinSta0), desktops (Default, Winlogon, Disconnect), and a shell. At session startup, UserInit runs profile scripts, if any, and the [Windows Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-entry), Explorer. The shell is a common interface and UI that applications use via the shell API that's exported by shell32.dll and shlwapi.dll. In particular here, the `ShellExecute[Ex]W` API function.

Comment: CMD is a text shell, which uses a console session that's hosted by an instance of conhost.exe, a GUI application that provides the window, console I/O buffers, and the console API. As of Windows 10, conhost.exe can also host a ConPTY console session, in which the UI itself is hosted by another application. The CMD shell has its own behavior and scripting language that date back to the mid 1980s, but it also integrates with the Windows shell API. If a file can't be executed directly, it tries calling `ShellExecuteExW`. With `start` it tries the latter even if it can't find a file.